# In a Cocoa macOS application, how to build two NSPredicates that filters all items or no items?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nspredicate

In a Cocoa macOS application, how to build two NSPredicates that filters all items or no items ? I remember there is either a specific format or method to call on NSPredicate but I cannot remember more. My specific problem is that I have a NSPredicate property that is bound to an NSArrayController filter predicate. Sometimes, for example when my NSSearchField string is @"", I want to display all items. I cannot set the property to nil because I use it to create a NSCompoundPredicate. I need in this case a valid NSPredicate that does not filter any item. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you check the documentation of `NSPredicate`?

Comment: The question is not particularly related to macOS or Cocoa. Please read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspredicate/1417329-predicatewithvalue?language=objc)

Comment: I have edited the question with more context. Thanks

Comment: Did you read the linked documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same need once, with the predicate being used in a NSCompoundPredicate. This will do the trick:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithValue:YES];
```

or

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithValue:NO];
```